# Choosing OpenShift Over DIY Kubernetes on Bare Metal: Benefits and Storage Management

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, openshift, redhat, upstream

Can someone shed some light on why I should use OpenShift instead of managing a bunch of kubeadm and automation to create a Kubernetes cluster on bare-metal Ubuntu nodes?

What are the differentiating features that OpenShift provides, and how does it handle storage management as part of Kubernetes cluster creation?

I have reviewed their documentation and articles, but I still don not have clarity on the differentiation.